# Preventing Cyrillic/Greek/Chinese in a string - C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, regex, unicode, latin

We have a system (using ASP.NET C# 4.0) that supports Greek, Cyrillic, Chinese characters. But  a third party system doesn't seem to work correctly.  To avoid issues when entering data for this third party system, I want to limit the text fields to accept only English or accented characters, but return a validation error for other characters.

How can I accomplish this? It seems I can use a regex along the lines of \p{Latin}, but C# doesn't seem to support this from my experience, as I get an `Unknown property 'Latin'` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET, the Unicode block properties need to be written with `Is...`:

```
[\p{IsGreek}\p{IsCyrillic}...]
```

A pattern like this would detect all offending characters in your case. If you just want to exclude everything but `Latin`, you could do something like:

```
[^\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}]
```

This covers all code points up to `U+024F`.

For a list of supported block names, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks).

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking for a list earlier but couldn't find it.  I had tried IsLatin, but I see that isn't on the list, you need to be more specific.  Perfect.